# How can IT audit for installation of IIS Express?

Tags: webserver, audit, iis, patching

[IIS Express](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/06/28/introducing-iis-express.aspx) is a developer tool for Windows XP and higher which provides the full feature set of IIS, but without needing administrator rights.

I've seen discussion by some developers who are considering bundling this with their application to make deployment consistent among versions.

If you read the [comments section](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/06/28/introducing-iis-express.aspx) in the link above, the blogger ScottG (and MSFT Corporate VP) mentions that instances of IIS Express will not receive updates via Windows update, but they *might* be updated when using Microsoft Update.

Since having unexpected and unpatched deployments of IIS Express in the environment of the application end-user can be an attack vector, how does their IT Security organization 
audit and detect the usage of this product?

Comment: The old version of IIS Express is called Cassini -- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cassini_Web_Server

Comment: Both IIS Express, and Cassini are different from [Hostable Web Core](http://blogs.iis.net/carlosag/archive/2008/04/14/host-your-own-web-server-in-your-application-using-iis-7-0-hostable-web-core.aspx) which is a sub component of IIS

Comment: @atdre apparently (havent used it yet...) IIS Express is intended to replace the older Cassini product, but its not just a relabelling...

Comment: @makerofthings, for the record note that this really only becomes a real issue when its configured to accept remote requests - which it does *not* by default.

Comment: I have case #111031460366444 open with Microsoft where they are recommending that I use IIS Express (or the HWC within IIS Express)  to accomplish my goal.  For that ticket I'm looking to create a software solution that works well with existing IT security policies.  I plan to sell to mid-size enterprises and the feedback I get will help shape my product (which version I use).

Comment: What deployment "environment" are you talking about?  In particular what do you mean by "install this with their application"?  You mention deployment, so do you really mean that developers design the installation procedure so IIS Express is shipped to end users along with their application?  And you want IT in the customer environment to notice IIS Express as contrasted with other sorts of servers, since it may not get patched?  Or are you asking about detecting this in a development environment?  Wouldn't you sort of expect to see developers using developer tools?

Comment: @nealmcb - Outside of developers using developer tools, Microsoft is recommending that an ISV consider installing IIS Express alongside the application for certain use cases.  Some consumers of the ISV application may not notice that this alternate IIS listener is installed or opened.  The most concerning is that it may not get patched along with WSUS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short and easy answer:  The same way you audit and detect installation of any other software.  You do do this, don't you?

Answer (score 8):

The obvious answer (if we accept your premise) is: routinely port-scan your own machines to see if they are running any unexpected services.

I'm not too sure about the premise that the best way to defend against this risk is to try to *detect* use of IIS Express.  I wonder if you have considered an alternative approach, which is not specific to any particular product:

- Developers should have full control over their machines, but those machines should be firewalled from the Internet.  There should be no open ports that are reachable from the outside Internet, without approval from security staff.
- There should be separate machines for deploying services to the rest of the world.  These machines should be under control of the ops folks, and the ops folks should have procedures governing which services they deploy on those machines.  The ops folks will probably require some form of change control, if they're good.  These machines can also be firewalled with a firewall policy that matches the expected services running on those machines, as a safety net to catch mistakes.

I think these two steps will take care of the problem.

Comment: I love your answer, now how do I convince management to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Win7 has AppLocker policies which are available via Group Policy. Group Policy, WMI, agentless, and/or Enterprise agent technology can be utilized to accomplish something similar.

In other words, use the Windows Forest/Domain and other technologies to set policies for clients on your network.